# Is 4.7.x end-of-life? Why does my site say that 4.7 has reached the end-of-life?

Tags: upgrade, 4.7, core, 5.0

The CiviCRM Status Screen is reporting for any version that is 4.7.x that it is End of Life.

[image]

What does this mean?   Is there something wrong with version 4.7?  Do I need to panic?

Answer (score 5):

There is a helpful explanation.  The numbering system changed, this is detailed [here](https://civicrm.org/blog/dev-team/v50-the-littlest-biggest-increment)

5.0.0 is the next version after 4.7.31 and is not a major update.

In The Q&A section there is an answer to this question which explains why the limitations of the update messaging system in 4.7 led to the decision to use the End of Life message in this instance:

> The in-app messaging in 4.7.x was hard-coded several years ago. For a site running the last 4.7.31, we can only display one of two messages -- either that 4.7.31 is up-to-date or that it 4.7 is end-of-life. Neither message is accurate or desireable -- the truth is that 4.7.x was renamed to 5.x.
>
> We've updated the notification system so that future messages can be
>   more nuanced/accurate, but for sites currently 4.7 we've had to take
>   an awkward approach. For April and May, we used the understated
>   message; but in June, we switched to the overstated message.

Comment: Indeed, I've been having to go through and let everyone whose sites I work on know that they don't have to worry about the message about 4.7.31. I didn't want them panicking.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to panic. That 4.7 is end of life means that no updates are released. It is usually good to have an update strategy (update with each release, update once a year, never update).

Comment: I'm not sure this adds anything to the existing answer and 4.7 is NOT End of Life, rather it has been renamed to 5.x as outlined in the blog post linked above.

Comment: Jaap is correct though in that 4.7 is technically End of Life 

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT in that is has been marked as such I would agree but surely we should be emphasising that it has only been marked as such due to a limitation of the update messaging system?

Comment: It should be noted that 4.7 is still supported in the sense there WILL be security updates for it - they will just not use the 4.7 numbering - so it's not end of life in the sense that would be of concern to people